# bytes To short method not working

Tags: java, android

I need to convert a bytes array to a short array. I dont know why it's not working! here is my code:

```
private short[] byte2short(byte[] buffer) {
   int byteArrsize = buffer.length;
   short[] shorts = new short [ byteArrsize/2];

   for (int i = 0; i < byteArrsize; i++) {

       short MSB = (short) buffer[2*i+1];
       short LSB = (short) buffer[2*i];
       shorts[i] = (short) (MSB << 8 | (255 & LSB));

    }

    return shorts;
}
```

Comment: Not Working - Please elaborate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered using the libraries built into Java for this?

```
private short[] byte2short(byte[] buffer) {
    ByteBuffer bytes = ByteBuffer.wrap(buffer);
    ShortBuffer shorts = bytes.asShortBuffer();
    return shorts.array();
}
```

It looks like the array method on `asShortBuffer()` might not work out as planned. But it's trivial to manually dump them:

```
private short[] byte2short(byte[] src) {
    short[] dest = new short[src.length / 2];
    ByteBuffer.wrap(src).asShortBuffer().get(dest);
    return dest;
}
```

Comment: No you only need one of them. The first one may work, depending on your implementation, but the second one should for sure.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one (from https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/HAI2OQW9arA):

```
private short[] byte2short(byte[] byteD) 
{
   int byteArrsize = byteD.length / 2;
   short[] shorts = new short[byteArrsize];
   for (int i = 0; i < byteArrsize; i++) {
       shorts[i] = (short) (byteD[i * 2] + (byteD[(i * 2) + 1] << 8));
   }
   return shorts;
}
```

Comment: it still gives me the same exception. ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException @rmooney